# What is this syntax in swift? factoryMethod()(self)

Tags: swift

So I was playing with lazy instantiation in Swift and attempting to replicate the following Objective C Paradigm exactly in swift

```
//A Getter for a strong property
- (SomeObject)lazilyLoadedObject {
    if (!_lazilyLoadedObject) {
        _lazilyLoadedObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
        __weak typeOf(self) weakSelf = self;
        _lazilyLoadedObject.blockProperty = ^(){//Some block which relies on weakSelf};
    }
    return _lazilyLoadedObject;
}
```

I then attempted to do the following and was surprised to find that the compilation failed with `Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!`

```
lazy var lazilyLoadedObject: SomeObject = {
    var instance = SomeObject()
    instance.closureProperty = {[weak self] in
        //Do something with weak self
    }
    return instance
}()
```

So my first question is, what is wrong with the above snippet for lazy instantiation when we need a reference to self?

Ever determined I then came upon the following snippet (mostly by virtue of code completion).

```
lazy var lazilyLoadedObject: SomeObject = instantiateLazilyLoadedObject(self)()
func instantiateLazilyLoadedObject() -> SomeObject {
        var instance = SomeObject()
        instance.closureProperty = {[weak self] in
            //Do something with weak self
        }
    return instance
}
```

What on earth is that^ (self)()?  A little googling suggests that it is a 'curried function' but I really don't understand.  What method is taking self as an argument and returning a function?  Is something being abstracted away and there is another layer I'm not seeing (perhaps there is a more verbose way to write this?).  And finally, is this the correct way to translate the top snipped of objective C to swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks strongly like a compiler bug (particularly since it shows up as a link failure rather than a compiler failure). I would open a radar. You should get a compiler-error (rather than a link error), or it should compile. You probably can't translate this to Swift right now.

But I can answer the second question. As you say, it's a curried function.

Every method is actually a function that takes "the object" as its first parameter in a curried way (wait for it; I'll explain).

Consider this:

```
struct X {
  func doit() { println("Yes") }
}
```

Simple. Now let's make one:

```
let x = X()
x.doit()
```

That outputs "Yes" just as you'd expect. But `x.doit()` is *exactly* the following:

```
X.doit(x)()
```

Crazy, what's with the double-parens? The method `doit` is really a function with the following signature:

```
func doit(self: X) -> (() -> Void)
```

This is a function that takes an `X` and returns a function that takes nothing and returns nothing. Read that again. It's a function that returns a function.

Currying (named after Haskell Curry) is the practice of converting a function that takes multiple parameters into a function that takes just one parameter and returns a function that takes the next parameter. In many situations this is incredibly convenient, and constructing methods is one of them.

So, `x.doit` (note that there are no parens; I mean the actual method itself) is *exactly* the same thing as `X.doit(x)` (which returns a function). I can assign either of these to another name:

```
let doitMethod = x.doit
let doitFunc = X.doit(x)
```

These two are identical. And I can make use of either of them as:

```
doitMethod()
doitFunc()
```

So that brings us back to the question. `instantiateLazilyLoadedObject` is a method. Or it is a function that takes an object and returns a function. Those two statements mean exactly the same thing. That said, `instantiateLazilyLoadedObject` is almost certainly a private implementation detail since it isn't in the Swift header (and it really, really sounds like an internal implementation detail). In the end, you're almost certainly hitting a compiler bug and should open a radar about that.

Comment: Interesting and very helpful.  Is there an obvious/logical reason why the language would have been designed this way (where all functions are abstractions of curried functions) or would it have just been an accidental side effect of design decisions taken to allow currying to be used?

Comment: It's a very simple & flexible way to allow methods to be treated as functions, so they can be be passed around as first-class objects. This was always a difficult thing to achieve in ObjC. You could pass function pointers, but not method pointers. I suspect currying was already chosen to be a feature, so it would have been a sensible application of currying rather than inventing some new technique to achieve it.